# Source Code for Node.js module HTTP

Tags: node.js

Regarding the source code for Node.js core modules. Supposedly, the npm installation only comes with a binary version of module HTTP. After googling for the source, I see the claim that the HTTP source code can be found on github, but I do not see it there. Where might one find the source for module HTTP?
. . .
Thanks for any assistance,
Tallisfan

Answer (score 8):

I believe what you are looking for lies in the /lib dir:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/master/lib

Comment: Don't you know where this module is in Ubuntu?

Comment: @Green I don't understand your question. My answer was to the original question, and is platform independent. Are you asking where node installs the source by default in Ubuntu? If you use the package manager I don't believe the source is installed, just binaries.

Answer (score 4):

The source is mixed with rest of the library. If you really need the source code, here's the [http.js](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/2cc7fa5e7dabdf10bf26efc4ab8dbffd36dba23e/lib/http.js) file found in the node.js [lib](https://github.com/nodejs/node/tree/2cc7fa5e7dabdf10bf26efc4ab8dbffd36dba23e/lib) folder that also contains most of the other http modules (see the remaining files starting with `_http`).

If you just needed to know what functions are available and what each of them do, I'd recommend referring to the [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_agent) instead.